# Как переписать по-нормальному ввод времени в нужном формате?

Tags: c++

Пишу для себя программу и более менее получается, но вот эта часть не радует :

```
string str_input;
size_t t_size = 12;
size_t count_symb = 0; 
size_t count_num = 0; 
size_t count_sum;
cout << "Введите начальное время в формате - 00:00:00,000 час/минута/секунда/миллисекунда\n";
do 
{
    getline(cin, str_input);
    if(str_input.length() > 0){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < str_input.length() && !(i > t_size); i++)
    {
    if((i == 2  && str_input[i] == ':') || (i == 5 && str_input[i] == ':') || (i == 8 && str_input[i] == ',') && (count_symb <= 3))
    {
        ++count_symb;
    }
    if((i != 2 || i != 5 || i != 8) && (str_input[i] >= '0' && str_input[i] <= '9') && (count_num <= 9))
    {
        ++count_num;
    }
}
count_sum = count_symb + count_num;
if(count_sum < t_size || count_sum > t_size) 
{
    count_symb = 0;
    count_num = 0;
    str_input = "";
    cout << "Неправльные данные! Повторите ввод.\n";
}
}

}
while(count_sum != t_size);
```

Что-то мне кажется этот код совсем плохой, особенно его объем и цифры в проверках. Могли бы вы переписать его исходя из своего опыта или как по вашему было бы правильно? И наставить меня этим на верный путь), потому что хорошо запоминаю и понимаю, если на примере своем что-то делается. Буду очень рад любым вариантам лучше этого, так как интересно как ещё можно реализовать это. Главное чтобы ввод заканчивался только при соблюдении шаблона 00:00:00,000

Comment: А почему не старый добрый `sscanf`?

Comment: @strol, Вы переименуйте, пожалуйста, вопрос, например, "Как переписать по-нормальному ввод времени в нужном формате?" Тогда и просмотров больше будет и может кому ещё ответ пригодится

Comment: @VladD, потому что я не знал о ней), теперь возьму на вооружение в будущем.
@Михаил М, переименовал.

Кстати, а как относится к навязыванию sscanf_s? Точнее к этому сообщению 'sscanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sscanf_s instead.
Стоит ли её использовать?

Comment: @strol, sscanf() работает везде, а sscanf_s() в винде. Решайте сами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Через sscanf будет приблизительно так:

```
int hour, min, sec, millisec;
if (sscanf(str_input.c_str(), "%02d:%02d:%02d,%3d", 
           &hour, &min, &sec, &millisec) != 4)
  cout << "Неправльные данные! Повторите ввод.\n";
```

Comment: Благодарю! Получил эстетическое удовлетворение. Не ожидал такого сокращения и простоты:).

Comment: Спасибо на добром слове :) . Но руку на отсечение за правильность не дам - на всякий случай проверьте вживую или по документации, что воспринимается только то, что нужно, и ничего лишнего (что без ведущих нулей ругается и т.п.)