# Использование Си в C++ программах : все за и против

Tags: c, c++, css

Нужно ли воспринимать возможность использовать Си в программах на С++, как приятное дополнение или относится только как к обратной совместимости?

Есть те, кто считает, что такое использование вредит пониманию, так как другой человек может быть не знаком с некоторыми частями Си или вовсе не знать ничего, кроме С++. Также некоторые считают это плохим стилем, потому что его использование делает код не красивым. Или же с точки зрения убеждений, что код должен содержать конструкции языка, на котором пишешь, а не смешивание new с malloc т.п.
Но а как же быстродействие некоторых его частей или использование удобных функций форматирования?

Где та грань, которой нужно придерживаться?

Я описал только малую часть, так как на большее не хватает знаний. По этому было бы прекрасно, если бы вы ответили не точно следуя этим вопросам, а опираясь на свой опыт и мнение и этим возможно тема раскроется ещё глубже, что в дальнейшем поможет и мне и возможно вам или кому-то другому.

**UPD:**
[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), на материал во второй ссылке буду постепенно поглядывать, но скорей для справки, чем искать повод для переезда на другой язык. Потому как в принципе я согласен со многим, даже при том, что у меня очень мало опыта. Мне кажется, что если начинать с С++, то это скорей будет изучение самого С++, а потом уже возможно через пару лет и программирования, что нельзя сказать про Си, так как он действительно прост в понимании, особенно после С++. И концентрация идет не на разбирание граблей языка или умения работать с stl/boost, а на освоение новых алгоритмов при написании своих костылей. Такие костыли будут в начале плохими и некрасивыми и на них будет уходить много времени в сравнении с использованием готовых решений на C++, но их написание даст понимание как это работает или как это выгодно модифицировать для своих нужд, а не просто использовать STL и даже может разбираться частично как работают его внутренности, но все ровно не быть способным написать что-то подобное на том же языке или другом.

Насчет первой ссылки, то встречал подобное и от самого автора(если не фейк) [тут](http://cs.mipt.ru/docs/comp/rus/develop/other/stroustrup_interview/) и должен сказать на том этапе знакомства с С++, меня это довольно сильно расстроило, так как неважно с какой целью началось изучения языка, но если видишь такое от его создателя, то это не может не задеть.

Наверное я бы выбрал Си, если бы вернулся в прошлое, но сейчас буду и дальше продолжать кодить с упором на С++ и поглядывать на С, то есть бежать наверх в низ по ступенькам. Потому что во мне преобладает непостоянность и я просто обязан закончить с этой книгой).
Вот такие пироги.

P.S. Спасибо за ответы и приношу извинения, если развел здесь оффтоп.

Comment: ну я читал что язык си был добавлен в с++ по причине того что на си уже много было написано, поэтому делаю вывод что коды на си можно использовать в с++ что бы не изобретать велосипед. да и много библиотек написаны на си к тому же.

Comment: @perfect "ну я читал что язык си был добавлен в с++ по причине того что на си уже много было написано" и где такое могло быть написано?

Comment: > Но а как же быстродействие некоторых его частей или использование удобных функций форматирования?

Вот это вот разъясните поподробнее.

Comment: @alexlz не вспомню где читал. но если вы против то не подключайте заголовки с *.h расширением и используйте типы только из std пространства

Comment: @perfect за что такие ограничения? Я Вам что-то плохое сделал?

Comment: @alexlz. да нет все норм. просто мне показалось что ты не согласен. извини если чем задел

Comment: @perfect да нет, никаких обид. Просто тезис непонятен. Многие считают, что именно совместимость с Си обеспечила выживание Си++. Так что, то, что "си был добавлен с си++" смотрится как-то странно.

Comment: @alexlz ну если честно то я представляю ситуацию так: с++ развивали из языка си по ходу развития языка рубили сишные недостатки и оставляли только совместимость

Comment: @perfect Noch eim Mal. Нельзя было сильно рубить сишные недостатки -- язык должен был сохранять совместимость. Так на ум приходит только требование наличия объявлений функций (прототипов).

Comment: @perfect, почитайте про историю создания С++, например в "Дизайн и Эволюция С++" Страуструпа.

Вкратце.


Никто не добавлял Си в С++. Наоборот, сначала к Си были добавлены классы и получился "C with Classes". Реализован он был в виде препроцессора к Си.

Затем автор пришел к выводу, что для адекватного выражения его идей нужны некоторые новые свойства, которые не получится сделать на уровне препроцессора, необходим полноценный компилятор, в результате появился С++.

Comment: @Михаил М: всё равно как-то не очень у вас пример. Внешний код не знает, при каких условиях строка остаётся валидной.

http://ideone.com/0L9oxF http://ideone.com/alTwuQ http://ideone.com/52elrC

Answer (score 13, accepted):

На самом деле, единой точки зрения на это нету.

С одной стороны, С — очень мощное подмножество языка, и используя его, можно легко «прострелить себе ногу», то есть, наделать глупых ошибок по незнанию.

Например, при помощи макросов можно сделать как много полезного, так и много [вредного](http://habrahabr.ru/post/197266/) наподобие `#define strcpy(a,b) memmove(a,b,strlen(b)+2)`, поэтому во многих проектах макросов стараются избегать — тем более, что при помощи гораздо более безопасных темплейтов можно сделать многое из того, что умеют макросы (и кроме того многое другое).

Другими частыми источниками ошибок являются смешивание `malloc`/`free` и `new`/`delete`/`delete[]` (по стандарту, `free(new int)` есть undefined behaviour), ручное управление памятью вместо использования смарт-указателей и RAII (источник 90% проблем новичков на ХК), использование массивов (и более продвинутое велосипедостроительство) вместо подходящих стандартных контейнеров `std::vector`, `std::map`, `std::stack` (источник остальных 90% проблем новичков). Особенно сложно даётся новичкам работа со строками (которая, нужно признать, в C организовано не блестяще): немногие осилят правильное чтение строки не известного заранее размера из файла!

С другой стороны, многие очень приятные лаконичные конструкции C не имеют прямого «безопасного» C++-варианта, например, [обсуждавшийся недавно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/261366/) `sscanf`.

Не стоит забывать, что C — *другой* язык, с другой идеологией, методологией и эстетикой, поэтому смесь кода на двух языках выглядит ненатурально и является источником ошибок.

Например, в C приветствуются лаконичные конструкции:

```
void copy_str(char *p, char *q)
{
    while (*q++ = *p++)
        ;
}
```

— в то время как в рамках C++ этот код слишком плотный, чересчур завязан на конкретные типы, слишком прямо работает с памятью и и слишком надеется на непроверяемые предусловия (априори считается, что `q` указывает на выделенный кусок памяти размером не менее `strlen(p) + 1`).

Для себя я установил правило: если пишется код на C++, стараться использовать идиоматичные конструкции, чтобы тем, кто читает мой код, было легче понимать его, и чтобы уменьшить вероятность ошибки: если выбран язык C++, а не C, надёжность более важна, чем экономия нескольких тактов процессора. Если же в каком-то месте я вижу необходимость использовать конструкцию из C, я пишу комментарий, обосновывающий эту необходимость.

В любом случае, присоединяясь к существующему проекту на C++, узнайте, какие там стандарты на использование конструкций чистого C, и следуйте им.

---

Update (спасибо @alexlz за комментарий!)

Заметьте, что в случае ограниченности ресурсов (программирование для контроллеров, например), использование «полноценного» C++ может быть неоправданно затратным. Это усугубляется тем, что компиляторы для таких платформ зачастую выдают плохо оптимизированный код.

В таких случаях распространённой практикой является отказ от всего множества языковых фич C++ и ограничение определённым подмножеством. Например, могут быть выброшены лямбды, шаблоны, стандартные контейнеры, исключения, стандартные алгоритмы, введено ручное управление памятью, то есть, итоговый язык будет ближе к чистому C. Но это — не от хорошей жизни (высокоуровневые конструкции позволяют забыть о надоедливых мелочах), и определяется опытным в разработке на данной платформе архитектором проекта.

Comment: @alexlz: Угу, у C++ до сих пор родовая травма в виде ужасной модели компиляции, в результате которой приходится указывать `#include` руками. По поводу utf-8 — я считаю, что строки должны быть в utf-8 лишь в сериализованном виде (например, в файле), а после десериализации их надо немедленно распаковывать в UCS-2 или даже лучше в UCS-4 (за исключением случаев проблем с памятью, но и тут лучше не экономить на спичках). И запаковывать назад при десериализации.

Comment: @VladD,
    
     строки должны быть в utf-8 лишь в сериализованном виде

почему так думаете? Не лучше б было, если б UTF-8 стал стандартной кодировкой C++ без сериализации ?

Comment: @0xFFh: мне кажется, это не настолько хороший вариант: с UTF-8 у вас не будет произвольного доступа по индексу за константное время, вам придётся каждый раз пробегать всю строку. (Unicode и так имеет много проблем наподобие combining characters, лучше не делать ещё сложнее.)

Comment: @VladD,

    с UTF-8 у вас не будет произвольного доступа по индексу за константное время, вам придётся каждый раз пробегать всю строку

так как любая строка в памяти - набор байт в памяти( кодировка лишь указывает на размер каждого символа в байтах ), то куда же девается константное время? Ведь зная детали кодировки, можно легко получить доступ к любому символу строки, отыскав нужное смещение от начала. Или я чего-то не понимаю?

По поводу "combining characters" соглашусь.

Comment: @0xFFh: не совсем :( Один символ в кодировке UTF-8 может занимать [от одного до шести байт](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Таким образом, чтобы выяснить, где начинается второй символ, надо сначала выяснить, сколько байт занимает первый. Для миллионного символа придётся просматривать все 999999 предыдущих.

Comment: @VladD не надо забывать о братьях наших меньших. Я не про зверей, а про программистов микроконтроллеров. C++ есть даже на 8-битных мелкосхемах, а уж про ARM'ы/avr32 и говорить нечего. А там ресурсы несколько ограничены.

Comment: @0xFF

     так как любая строка в памяти - набор байт в памяти( кодировка лишь указывает на размер каждого символа в байтах ), то куда же девается константное время?

путаете мягкое с тёплым. Последовательный просмотр строки -- ни разу не константное (O(1) ) время. Но @VladD это уже подробно расписал.

Comment: @alexlz: например, в C# или там Java.

Вот вам пример, где это бьёт по разработчику.
Если у вас есть классы A и B, ссылающиеся друг на друга, в C++ приходится идти на трюк: в `a.h` вместо `#include "b.h"` писать форвард-декларацию `class B;`, определять поля только через указатель, и не использовать inline-определения функций, работающих с `B`. В C# компилятор компилирует в два прохода: сначала читает все имена классов/методов, а потом тела этих методов, так что ни проблемы, ни даже самой необходимости в `#include` не возникает.

Comment: @VladD 

    так что ни проблемы, ни даже самой необходимости в #include не возникает.

Но using/import'ы там есть. Пусть они не голый текст, как у C/C++, но тем не менее.

Comment: @alexlz: `using`, строго говоря, избыточен: без него тоже всё работало бы, только приходилось бы указывать полные имена, с namespace'ами. Подключение модуля на уровне проекта, да, нужно, но этот модуль при этом не будет перекомпилирован (как происходит с `#include`-нутыми файлами). В частности, никакой аналог

    #define class struct
    #include "something.h"

не возможен в принципе: подключаемый модуль уже скомпилирован.

(Или [вот такое](http://hashcode.ru/questions/201310#201328) ещё.)

Comment: @VladD что касается макроподстановок -- это привет из прошлого. Их минусы были очевидны десятилетия назад. Конечно, совсем без них тяжело, и они появляются даже в современных языках, уж про "макро на стероидах" -- templates в Си++ можно и не вспоминать, но вот препроцессор, плюющий и на синтаксис языка, и на семантику -- архаизм. В 70е годы -- да, круто, в XXI веке -- увы.

А насчёт перекомпиляции -- увы, сильно увеличивает время трансляции, но у языка огромная пользовательская база, и исправить что-то практически невозможно.

Comment: @alexlz: так и есть. Вот это (постоянная перекомпиляция) и есть «родовая травма»: при «рождении» языка пришлось делать так, чтобы быть совместимым с C, а теперь уж ничего исправить нельзя. Аминь.

Answer (score 10):

[@strol](/users/14769/strol), программирование само по себе достаточно сложная штука.

Язык должен помогать как можно проще и естественней выражать свои мысли. На самом деле С++ язык сложный (а ведь создавался с целью упростить программирование на Си).

Поэтому старайтесь писать проще (однако, не проще, чем необходимо) и не слишком переживайте по поводу смешения стилей. Конечно, некоторые вещи, которые на первый взгляд эквивалентны, могут на самом деле оказаться несовместимыми (например, new/delete и malloc/free). Просто о них надо знать, т.е. понимать  как реализуются разные конструкции. В самом С++ полно взаимозависимых вещей и добавление чего-то из чистого Си ситуацию не упрощает (но и далеко не всегда усложняет).

Примерно на эту тему мне понравилось высказывание Кернигана (кстати, они работали с Страуструпом в Bell labs) в интервью из книги ["Пионеры программирования"](http://padabum.com/d.php?id=51616)

```
...Си занимает прочную позицию среди языков программирования. Он чрезвычайно выразителен, но в то же время не слишком сложен или велик, а кроме того, написанные на нем программы эффективны. ... С этим языком удобно работать, потому что если нужно что-то выразить, он представляет для этого не так много разных способов. Я посмотрю на ваш код и скажу: да, мне понятно, что он делает. Едва ли то же самое можно сказать о таких языках, как Perl или С++. Я посмотрю на ваш код и останусь в недоумении, потому что тут есть много способов написать одно и то же.

C++ сложен и огромен, и выразить что-либо можно многими способами. Если мы с вами будем писать на C++, то можем прийти к весьма разным способам описания какой-нибудь большой задачи. В Си такого не бывает. Си сохранился потому, что у него оказалось хорошее соотношение выразительности и эффективности, и для важных приложений он остается лучшим инструментом.

.... Бьерн голову себе сломал, пытаясь добиться максимальной совместимости с Си. Одной из причин успеха C++ в сравнении с другими языками была хорошая совместимость на уровне как исходного, так и объектного кода, а это означало отсутствие необходимости полностью перестраивать работу, чтобы использовать C++ в среде Си.

.... Одним из крупнейших прегрешений считают чрезмерную близость к Си....

... Возможно, но чем дальше он отошел бы от Си, тем меньше были бы его шансы на успех. Здесь трудно соблюсти правильную меру, и я думаю, что он очень хорошо справился со своей задачей.
```

*(приношу извинения за столь длинную цитату)*

А некоторые люди вообще высказываются о программировании на С++ довольно кратко, но [значительно резче](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/57918).

[Здесь](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/) весьма обстоятельная критика.

Так что, изучайте все получше и делайте выводы сами для себя.

Comment: @avp Ну об ответе Торвальдса что можно сказать: грубый, невоспитанный швед. Полтавы ему не хватает.

Comment: @alexlz: Для Полтавы нужен свой Пётр I, кого выдвинем в кандидатуры?

Comment: @VladD Ну раз пошла такая пьянка, импортируем Уильяма Гейтса. Хотя, по молодости лет у Л. Торвальдса какие-то разногласия и с Таненбаумом (в переводе на русский -- Ёлкиным) были...

Comment: @alexlz: Хм, что-то образ Билли в очочках не вяжется с Петром Первым у меня в голове. Хотя, Пётр прорубил окно в Европу, а Билл посадил на окна весь мир, так что параллели имеются :-)

Answer (score 2):

ИМХО, основное достоинство С - возможность написания быстрых программ. А если не быстрых, то совместимых/работающих с быстрыми. С++ - это С с немного более человеческим лицом. Но основная идея - по-прежнему скорость. Допустим, в std::list вы не найдёте метода sort. Хотя, конечно, есть дополна простых, но неэффективных методов типа std::find или insert в vector... Ну что поделаешь, какую-то цену за удобство надо платить.

Это всё я к тому, что я считаю возможность смешивания С++ и С стилей одним из главных достоинств языка. Ну лень тебе сегодня - завёл vector<string>. А завтра оказалось, что это всё тормозит - заменил vector на vector<char *>, память выделил один раз на все строки, раздал и всё! Я даже память для массивов частенько выделяю через

```
std::string m_memory; ...

m_memory.resize(data_size);
return m_memory.c_str()
```

Как ни странно, ни разу сильно не огребал из-за подобных шалостей. Гораздо тяжелей было научиться работать со строками без access violation'ов в С, когда только начинал :)

**Upd:** [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd), ну естественно не на стеке! Имеется в виду член класса, который живёт дольше, чем используется память, которую он держит. Я потому и написал m_:

```
class C {
private:
  std::string m_memory; ...

  char *GetWorkMemory(int data_zize) {
    m_memory.resize(data_size);
    return m_memory.c_str();
  } ...
```

Comment: @Михаил М

    С++ - это С с немного более человеческим лицом. 

Странные у Вас понятия о человечности.

Comment: return m_memory.c_str()

это такое есть в коде? Если сигнатура функции `const char * ..... ();` , то это ещё ничего. Но если там нет константности - очень плохо. [Почитайте](http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/2008/01/const.html).

Comment: Да уж, в очередной раз замечаешь, насколько прав Линус.

Comment: на чистом си такое сделать также не сложно. Никто не мешает объявить массив на стеке и вернуть указатель на него.

Comment: @KoVadim, конечно можно. А можно просто на ноль поделить.

Я имел в виду слова Линуса:

    It's made more horrible by the fact that a lot of substandard programmers use it...

о том, почему С++ ужасный язык.

Ведь по сути-то (если отбросить все коровье дерьмо) он говорит о том, что в проектах на Си (а не крестах) язык выступает просто в качестве фильтра.

Comment: Вы серьёзно? Вы вернули дохлый указатель на память в разрушающемся фрейме, и ещё ни разу не огребли от архитектора?

---
Для справки: доступ к памяти, возвращаемой `.c_str` после смерти или изменения строки есть undefined behaviour.

Comment: @VladD, помню как-то не мог понять в чем дело на примере с простыми типами. Вернул указатель на локальную переменную функции, а никаких ошибок не было и значение по адресу правильное было. А потом уже спросил у кого-то и сказали что память помечается как свободная, но не очищается, то есть может быть занята кем-то, а может и нет, по этому и undefined behaviour.

Comment: @strol, на самом деле, если Вы возвращаете адрес локальной переменной в завершившейся функции и тут же (до  вызова какой-нибудь другой функции (м.б. неявного)) используете это значение (копируете по "valid" адресу), то ничего страшного не произойдет.

Но только до того момента, как именно в это же время не возникнет прерывание от системного таймера, а Вам уже пришел сигнал, который Вы же и обрабатываете, а обработчик сигнала не использует альтернативный стек.

Вот.

Но лучше такие штуки на делать. Надо что-то вернуть из функции - возвращайте по-человечески, даже структуру.

Comment: @avp: Использовать дохлую переменную всё равно как-то неправильно. Даже если я в коде клонирую значение сразу, оптимизатор имеет законное право превратить «сразу» в «попозже», с него станется. С другой стороны, мёртвый объект может содержать указатели на освобождённую память в куче, которую может захватить другой поток даже без прерываний.
В общем, повторю ваши слова, лучше такие штуки не делать. Делать правильно не так тяжело.

Comment: @VladD, ну сегодня прямо день UB!

Я по поводу Вашего комментария с "баг в linux kernel" (в другом вопросе).

Думаю, что это посто глупая ошибка в коде. Кто-то заметил ее (и хорошо). Там дальше есть ссылка на патч. 

Хотя, в принципе в ядре возможно почти все (кроме плавающей арифметики). Наверняка этого нет, но мы же не видим класс памяти указателя. Теоретически (уверен, что этого в ядре нет) при прерывании его можно и подправить... А можно вычислить адрес указателя на struct socket и заполнить его, а потом вернуться на пару команд дальше.

--

Непонятно, почему это вызвало такую дискуссию.

Comment: @avp: угу :) Смысл комментария о баге был такой: в коде был UB (разыменование NULL-указателя), и компилятор воспользовался этим и «съел» и проверку на NULL, и segmnetation fault. Это могло быть и причиной бага, который мы обсуждали, т.к. ситуация аналогична.

Comment: > если Вы возвращаете адрес локальной
> переменной в завершившейся функции и
> тут же (до вызова какой-нибудь другой
> функции (м.б. неявного)) используете
> это значение (копируете по "valid"
> адресу), то ничего страшного не
> произойдет.
> 

А если на примере вашего кода [здесь][1], считается ли дохлой переменная res из функции fromsec и безопасно ли её тут же присваивать другой переменной? То есть вот так `struct miltim sm = fromsec(msec);`. Или же может быть то, что говорил VladD : 

> оптимизатор имеет законное право
> превратить «сразу» в «попозже»


  [1]: http://goo.gl/pQ0FaM

Comment: @strol: хороший вопрос! Нет, код @avp совершенно правилен, т. к. из функции возвращается не _указатель_ на память непонятно где (как это было в случае `.c_str()`), а _копия_ структуры `miltim`. «Оригинал» этой структуры, конечно, умрёт вместе с фреймом. (Современные оптимизаторы умные, и обычно излишнее копирование убирают при оптимизации.)

@avp не сможет вам ответить тут, у него закончился лимит комментариев.

Comment: То есть проблема имеет быть только с указателем или ссылкой и не важно на какую они память указывают, то ли кучи, то ли стека?
А если аргументом функции будет другая функция, которая вернет адрес и дальше он присваивается параметру функции и это будет аналогично тому если бы сразу же присвоилось какой-нибудь переменной? Или финт, который описал avp уже не пройдет?

Comment: @strol: Проблема не с указателем, а с _той памятью, на которую он указывает_. Можно честно выделть память при помощью `new` и вернуть указатель (и права владения!) на неё: эта память будет жива до того момента, как клиент прочитает её и удалит сам при помощи `delete`. Но с `.c_str` дело обстоит по-другому: эта функция возвращает память, которой владеет сам объект `std::string`, и которую он имеет право убить (деаллоцировать) в своём деструкторе (а также при смене значения строки). Возвращать указатель на память, принадлежащую умирающему объекту — неправильно.

Comment: @strol: То есть, память по указателю, полученному из `.c_str`, можно использовать лишь пока (1) строка жива, и (2) её контент не поменялся.

---
Точно так же нельзя возвращать указатели на объекты умирающего стек-фрейма, т. к. они умрут вместе с фреймом.

Comment: @alexlz, под человечностью я понимаю возможность хранения и конкатенации строк, например. А не char string_buf1[1000]; strcpy(string_buf1 + strlen(string_buf1), string_buf2); Или strdup с постоянными free